# DataInputStream read mp3 file

Tags: java, mp3, datainputstream

I am following this specification of the mp3 filetype.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/26901-mp3-file-structure-howto/

What I'm doing here is reinventing the wheel - mostly for learning purposes. Thing is, this is more low-level than I'm used to, so I really don't know what I'm doing. I have the file input set up all right, I know that much, here's what I have for reading that file...

`dis` is a DataInputStream pointing to a .mp3 file.

```
public void play(){
    System.out.println("Read:\n-----------\n\n");
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            System.out.println(dis.readByte());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My output looks like this...

```
Read:
-----------


73
68
51
3
0
0
0
1
47
118
67
79
77
77
0
0
0
33
```

(...)

So, my question is, what does this mean? Shouldn't the first printed value be 255 because the header of an mp3 frame is all full bits? What do I do from here to continue extracting meaningful data from the file?

Comment: it's fair to say that this is beyond your control - but somebody who has done it will budge you in the right direction; I think you will get tired of it pretty soon

Comment: 73, 68, 51 are the characters "ID3" which is an indicator that there is [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) format metadata in the file.